# Как выбрать option в Angular JS с помощью массива?

Tags: angularjs

Есть такой код:

```
<select ng-model="data.languageArraySelected" class="tokenize-sample" multiple="multiple" id="language" required>
         <option ng-value="{{key}}" ng-repeat="(key, value) in data.languageArray | orderBy">{{value}}</option>
</select>
```

Format `data.languageArraySelected` is: `[11,6]`, мне нужно выделить select option где `{{key}} == element from [11,6]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы выбрать option необходимо присвоить `ngModel` (в вашем случае `data.languageArraySelected`) элемент массива, например, `data.languageArraySelected = data.languageArray[индекс элемента]`.